# Use of latent semantic analysis in topic modeling

Tags: svd, latent-variable

I am learning Latent Semantic Analysis. After we have the SVD decomposition of term-document matrix, how to infer topics from that?

For example, how to get the following result:

Topic 1: apple, orange, fruit
Topic 2: computer, machine